# TLS renegotiation support in TLS version 1.2

Tags: tls1.2

Regarding TLS Renegotiation in tls version 1.2, there are a few queries as enlisted below.

1. Does the ssl session id remains constant for the entire lifetime of an established ssl connection(tls version 1.2)?
2. If tls re-negotiation is supported in tls 1.2, and then on tls renegotiation taking place on the same connection, will ssl session id remains same?
3. In tls re-negotiation, is it allowed to update the SAN value?

I tried reading about tls renegotiation support in tls 1.2, but still I have above listed queries unanswered. Please help me with above queries or guide me to approriate resource. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: (0) this is not a programming or development question, which is the topic of StackOverflow; it would be more suitable on security.stackexchange.com (1) where I already answered at least some of it in https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91248/questions-about-triple-handshakes-considered-harmful- but note that was written in 2015 and as you appear to know (since you ask specifically 1.2) TLS1.3 in 2018 removed renegotiation entirely, although it added new methods for post-handshake client auth and rekey. ...

Comment: ... (2) If a renegotiation is a full handshake (i.e. not a resumption) it can change any and all security parameters including the server cert, including any and all fields in that cert, including SAN. It could also change the (client-side) SNI which could _cause_ a change to the server's choice of cert. (3) requesting offsite resources is offtopic in _most_ stackexchange sites with limited exceptions like softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085. One more query, I'm working on a spring boot application that uses reactive netty as server. I've a use case for which I want to know if the sessionId value provided by ServerWebExchange.getRequest().getSslInfo().getId() returns remains constant for a connection, or will it change if tls renegotiation takes place between server and client?